# Wall UI control other than FluidKit

Tags: c#, wpf

How could somebody create a wall effect like this in a WPF application?

[image]

I have seen the Fluidkit controls but it only shows 5 items per line instead of the multitude of items per line in the image below.

Comment: updated the link. https://imageshack.com/scaled/large/809/t8k7.jpg

Comment: Is that supposed to be... *usable*? Or just for show?

Comment: @user1842134 I've edited your question and added the new link, however in future just edit your own question and make updates, than add it as comments

Comment: I would like it to be usable in the sense that a user can click on an image and it would launch a specific event depending on the image clicked.

Comment: What is the name of above app?

Comment: I do  not know, it was an image I saw on google with no particular name or indication of the software used